# What is the Opposite of "position:fixed" - CSS

Tags: css

i am working with Css and i don't know What is the Opposite of "position:fixed" ?

CSS:

```
position:fixed
```

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: there is no "opposite" the closest opposite is `position:relative;`

Comment: what do you mean opposite? If you want to 'un-do' position:fixed, do it position: static

Comment: Try googling for "css positioning" and read it! It would be very helpful to you. Then you can try "css positioning example" for real examples...

Comment: What is the Opposite of "245" ?

Comment: Here's a nice article on positioning: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`position:static;`, `position:absolute;`, and `position:relative;` are the alternatives to `position:fixed;`. There isn't a definitive opposite, because `relative`, `absolute`, `static`, and `fixed` have different properties to behave differently.

Take a look at this article:

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 3):

"Default value: static" (seems an opposite to fixed as it shows where is placed and scrolls with the content)

```
position: static;
```

**Probably you should edit your question and use "which are the alternatives of position: fixed"!**

Answer (score 0):

These  are other properties for position in CSS

```
position:static
position:absolute
position:relative
position:inherit
```

Comment: and position: inherit

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have two elements

```
<div class="sidenav col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="main-content col-sm-9"></div>
```

For those who assumed adding affixed so the sidenav / sidebar element forget it, this just makes things a pain in the backside. You don't need to use the affixed plugin and certainly don't go a long the lines of what I was thinking and write a jquery plugin to toggle the sidenav element class.

The solution is simple and it just revolves around media queries and a very minor css change (i know right). In my example I want my sidenav element to not scroll on anything higher than a mobile screen, so simple solution is add these two media queries.

```
/* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid
================================================================================= */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidenav {

    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  div.sidenav.col-sm-3{
        position:static;

  } 

}

/* On Larger Screens
================================================================================= */

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

        div.sidenav.col-sm-3{
            position:fixed;

        } 

    }
```

In a nutshell I have simply added two media queries to solve the problem. We were all thinking way too complicated. Well any of us having not attempted this previously.

The first query I added was to tell all larger screened devices that I wanted to FIX the position of my sidenav element to the left and prevent it from scrolling. I achieved this by adding the position attribute to the query with the 'fixed' value.

The second query simply resets this attribute value for mobile devices to 'static'. For any who don't know the default of any positioned element is static.

Check the code and just play around with screen sizes as you feel fit but it's working for me. Enjoy your weekend lads. Digital hi-5

FYI IF this doesn't work for you then chances are you experienced what I did first time around and qualify your css a little more. For example don't just style as .classname{position:fixed;} instead use specificity rulings and something like firefoxes firebug tool. click on the element (if you need too) and fully qualify as much as needed your css so for example

instead of this .sidenav{position:fixed}
do this div.sidenav.col-sm-3{position:fixed}

In your example you may need to specify a little more or less, everyones markup will differ :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `position: sticky` would be the closest opposite because `position: fixed` elements stay positioned at one location relative to the view port and don't change their `position`. Whereas, sticky elements change their location relative to the viewport while also dynamically change their `postion`.