# CSS - media queries / RWD , logo image file hiding behind fixed nav

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on the media queries for a site and I'm stuck on a static logo image which sits within the header but only when the screen size is `min-width 960px`.

Above that size I have an interactive particle logo image but when the screen is reduced down to mobile-size I just want a logo in the header. The problem is the logo simply isn't showing. I suspect it is being hidden by the nav bar which is fixed in position.

This is how I have my code at the moment -

```
<header>
        <div id="logo"> <img src="images/havoc_logo.png"> </div>
        <nav>
            <a href="#particle-slider">Home</a>
            <a href="#whatwedo">What we do</a>
            <a href="#whoweare">Who we are</a>
            <a href="#partners">Who we work with</a>
            <a href="#contact">Say hello</a>
            <a href="Blog">Blog</a>
        </nav>
</header>
```

**styles.css/media queries**

```
 #logo {

  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#logo img {

   width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

/* RWD for logo (particle-slider is id for interactive logo) */

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {


    #particle-slider {
        display: none;
    }


}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {

    #logo img {

        display: none;
    } 


}

     @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    body {
    max-width: 500px;

}


  header {

    height: auto;

  }

  nav {

    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;

  }

  nav a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 0;


  } 


  #logo {

    height: auto;

  }

  #logo img {

    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

So, when I shrink the page right down to 480px or less then nothing shows in the header other than the nav bar. How do I show the logo image in the header when I shrink the page?

Comment: pls provide a working jsfiddle

Comment: According to your code, for the large sizes (min-width:480px), you have hide the the main logo and less than 480px, then logo will show in your page.

So what do you need to do exactly?

Comment: @sajee My problem is, the logo is not showing when I shrink the screen and I need to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with this Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252631/what-is-the-opposite-of-positionfixed-css)

Basically my nav was held in a fixed position and covering the logo so I had to revert the `position:fixed` rule to `position:static`